# Stumped on why MySQL won't accept my query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Okay, so I'm currently using mysqli_real_escape_string to escape my SQL queries before sending them to MySQL via PHP. Yet, for some reason my queries aren't processing, and when I outputted the MySQL query and pasted it in to PHPMyAdmin, it gave the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ind={A$RTkAIqah0J1N$Fqymnud9s5PwnWw2wC.Y02oDo4H3W8QJPoJ$6$KK8UearuUCDH$FQg' at line 1
```

Now, the following is my query:

```
INSERT INTO `db`.table(`colheader`) VALUES ('{\"hey\":[\"Hello world\",\"7\\/9\\/2013\"]}') WHERE ind='$6$RTkAIqah0J1N$Fqymnud9s5PwnWw2wC.Y02oDo4H3W8QJPoJ$6$KK8UearuUCDH$FQgSnLHIlkBOtDTzu9AuZIZTr6GS4Rzr.iW11041994'
```

Now, I know that the string assigned to 'ind' has some issues, but I tried putting a slash before every period and every dollar sign and it still doesn't work. I tried putting the whole thing in double quotes, even brackets. Nothing. Could anyone point out what I'm clearly missing? I've looked at the documentation and can't seem to find anything. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: There is no `WHERE` in `INSERT`. This statement is only for `SELECT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE`.

Comment: `INTO` is the equivalent of `WHERE` So, when using `INSERT` there is **NO** `WHERE` clause

Comment: It looks like you need to re-read the documentation on `INSERT` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` serves to filter which records will be affected or retrieved by your query, and `INSERT` servers to append a whole new record to a table.

An `INSERT` can never affect existing records, therefore its nonsense to have a `WHERE` clause. `INSERT` does not support `WHERE`.

If you are trying to edit the value of a field on an existing record, use `UPDATE` instead.

Take a look at the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) for details about its usage.

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to make an update to the specified index use

```
UPDATE `db`.table SET `colheader` = '{\"hey\":[\"Hello world\",\"7\\/9\\/2013\"]}' WHERE ind='$6$RTkAIqah0J1N$Fqymnud9s5PwnWw2wC.Y02oDo4H3W8QJPoJ$6$KK8UearuUCDH$FQgSnLHIlkBOtDTzu9AuZIZTr6GS4Rzr.iW11041994'
```